# Given a list, what was not found

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I have a table of rows:

```
COL1, COL2
1,    ABC
2,    CDE
3,    XYZ
```

Given a string input `('ABC', 'CDE', 'BBB')` is it possible to write SQL that will tell me `'BBB'` was not found?  The opposite to:

```
select COL2 from TABLE where COL2 in ('ABC', 'CDE', 'BBB');
```

Note that the list could contain any number of items, so having `UNPIVOT` (on Oracle) does not seem to be the answer.

What's my alternative?

Comment: ah, thanks - I will try this and close if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by putting the values in a CTE or table:

```
with values as (
      select 'ABC' as val from dual union all
      select 'CDE' from dual union all
      select 'BBB' from dual
     )
select *
from values v
where not exists (select 1 from table t where t.col2 = values.val);
```

Comment: Just not dynamic with the input list.

Comment: I like the answer, however as Maheswaren says, it's not dynamic.  How do I turn that input list into something usable - even populating a table?

Comment: @user3123546 . . . Instead of inputting the value as a list, input it as a series of `select` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how this might be accomplished dynamically:

```
WITH x1 AS (
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('ABC,CDE,BBB', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS val FROM dual
   CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('ABC,CDE,BBB', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT x1.val
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM mytable t1
                     WHERE t1.val = x1.val );
```

Just replace `ABC,CDE,BBB` with whatever your list of values might be.